# How do I get a count of items with identical IDs in a mySQL table?

Tags: mysql

I have a table called Users_Answers which holds (duh) what users have answered.

Each answer has an Answer_id column which points to a specific answer, meaning, there's an Answers table that has 10 answers, where every answer has an id (1-10), and whatever answer the user picks, that column gets set with referencing the Answer column.

What I need to do is get a count of how many times each answer has been picked. At the moment, I'm doing a really ugly join on the users, which works, but takes for ever and is totally unnecessary, since I don't care, in this instance, what the individual user has selected, but rather just need an aggregate total of how many times each one of the 10 answers has been picked.

I know there's a totally simple and elegant way to get this to happen, but I'm totally stumped.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
select answer_id, count(*) as total from user_answers group by answer_id
```

Answer (score 2):

`select answer_id, count(*) from Users_Answers group by answer_id` ?

Comment: downed beat you by a minute, but I up ticked both of you :)

Comment: Actually I beat him by 24 seconds (2011-09-06 23:49:50Z vs 2011-09-06 23:50:14Z) - but indeed, 'too close to call' :). Thanks